# Restart php-fpm after php.ini modification

Tags: php, nginx

I modify the php.ini in /etc/php.ini in CENTOS and for the change to make effect running.
    service nginx restart
isn't enough and I have to run
    service php-fpm restart
any idea why the restarting of the nginx doesn't reload the php.ini?

Comment: This is more for superUser !

Comment: because unlike apache they're 2 separate daemons, in apache php runs within apache, in an nginx setup you have the nginex daemon and you have the php-fpm daemon.  If you edit the php ini you restart php-fpm not nginx restarting nginx serves no purpose for you.  think of the "webserver" side of things as simply a proxy rather than an apache style webserver

Comment: `/etc/init.d/php-fpm reload`